# OOP, Python – class inheritance or attribute assignment

Tags: python, oop

Let's say we have two classes – `Car` and `Engine`. The question is would it be more reasonable to inherit `Car` from `Engine` to use `Engine`'s methods (e.g. `start()`) or to use `Engine` as an attribute of a `Car`?

First approach (obvious):

```
class Car(Engine):
    # do smth with inherited methods
```

Second approach:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, engine)
        self.engine = engine

    def start(self):
        return self.engine.start()

class EngineV4():
    def start(self):
        pass

class EngineV8():
    def start(self):
        pass

# usage
engine = EngineV8()
car = Car(engine)
```

Also a version – to subclass a `Car`:

```
class V8Car(EngineV8, Car): pass
```

The first approach at some point looks good but leads to inheritance of literally everything a car has (e.g. `Car(Engine, Lights, Wheels)`.
I guess, it's not a purpose of inheritance in OOP, not to mention that lights are not car in common sense to be inherited from.

The second approach allows a car to use different engines, for example.

The third approach leads to the same problem as the first one, except it's on the other level of abstraction.

So, what is the most logical way of implementing such things? I understand that the question is more about OOP basics than Python and curios where to read more about such cases.

Comment: Is a car a type of engine?

Comment: Both V4 and V8 engines are *an engine*. Inheritance makes sense there. A car OTOH *is* not *an engine*.

Comment: @khelwood,  No, it's not, that's why I think inheritance is not the option here (`Lights` example in the question). And also why the question appeared in the first place.

Comment: Seems like you already know the answer then. Are you asking for people's agreement?

Comment: Whichever provides the most code reuse.

Comment: @khelwood, no, what I'm suggesting is just my point of view. It may be (and probably is) wrong, that's why I'm asking more experienced people which way is correct.

Comment: @sytech nope, whichever is semantically correct - in this case the second solution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you're right. I did not give enough care to the question, sorry.  I glanced at the question and thought it was asking something to the effect of "should `circle` be a subclass of `ellipsis` or the other way around". (There is no *correct* answer there). I should clarify my suggestion by saying *in absence of an obvious answer*, one should probably choose what provides the most code reuse.

Comment: I notice someone voted to close this as "primarily opionion based". I invite this person to carefully read the first part of the GoF's "Design patterns" book. As far as I'm concerned I've had (more than once) to work with/maintain code written using inheritance the wrong way and I can tell you it's definitly not a matter of mere opinion - bad design leads to unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Khelwood mentions in a comment, ask yourself: "is a car a type of engine ?".

Semantically, inheritance describes a "is a" relationship - if "B" inherits from "A", then "B" is a "A" (cf [liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). From this point of view, a "car" is not an "engine", it has an engine, so you want composition ("has a" relationship).

Technically - specially in dynamically typed languages like Python where you don't strictly need inherance for subtyping -, inheritance (implementation inheritance I mean) is also a restricted and static form of composition/delegation so you might see code using inheritance mostly for implementation reuse, but this is still debatable from a design POV  ( (this might be ok when factoring out common stuff in a TestCase suite but that's about it) and does definitly not apply to your example.

As a general rule, only use inheritance when you really have a "is a" relationship, else use composition/delegation.

Edit: I just noticed this in your question:

```
class V8Car(EngineV8, Car): 
    pass
```

This is exactly what you want to avoid, both semantically and technically. Some of the problems you will get with this design:

1/ A car's engine is a replaceable part so you should be able to change it without changing the car itself. How will you deal with this when your customer asks you to add this "little feature" that was "so obvious" that it wasn't part of the initial requirements ?

2/ You are going to need one subclass for possible each car / engine combination, and you will need to create a new car subclass each time you add a new engine type. Good luck maintaining this... Now add wheels and a few other features and and figure out how many classes you end up with.

3/ if you add a new attribute/method to Engine that happens to shadow an existing Car attribute, all you client code will break - in an obvious way if you're lucky, but often in a more subtle way that might not be systematic nor immediatly detected. Then once you find out you broke something, you will have to edit all impacted classes to make sure the attribute is correctly resolved on `Car`, not on `Engine`, and remember to port this fix to all new car/engine combinations too. And that's in the lucky case where there's no other implication - you might have (well, you *probably* have) some method in Engine that uses this attribute for some computation, but then those methods will start using the Car's attribute instead and then how are you going to fix this ?

Some of the above points may look like strawmen arguments, but I've seen such things happening IRL and fixing them was a real mess - and a huge net loss for the company.

Now compare with what you get by making Engine a component of Car:

```
class Engine():
   # ... 

class Car():
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.engine = engine

car = Car(engine=Engine())
```

1/ A car's engine is a replaceable part so you should be able to change it without changing the car itself

```
# Yeah we got this even better engine!
car.engine = V8SuperEngine()
```

2/ You are going to need one subclass for possible each car / engine combination, and you will need to create a new car subclass each time you add a new engine type

```
# don't need a new class...
newcar = Car(engine=V8SuperEngine())
```

3/ if you add a new attribute/method to Engine that happens to shadow an existing Car attribute, all you client code will break

```
# Well, now this just cannot happen, period. Something else ?
```

Comment: Related: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation is more useful approach for this task because it allows construct concrete car dynamically, like this:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, engine, wheels):
        self.engine = engine
        self.wheels = wheels
...

some_car = Car(concrete_engine, concrete_wheels)
```

work with aggregated objects (for higher cohesion), like this method:

```
def speed(self):
    if self.wheels.is_locked(): 
        return 0
    return self.engine.swiftness() * self.factor
```